# Hibernate update table with unique constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Have an application that has a table with a date column set as unique.  Unique is set so that there will always only be one record per day in the table.

The following code updates the information in the table when run for the x'th time during the day:

```
else{
      StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("from Weather where COLUMN_DATE = '" + weatherData.getDate() + "'");
      List weatherDat = session.createQuery(query.toString()).list();
      if (weatherDat.size()>0) {
          Weather curWeather = (Weather) weatherDat.get(0);
          curWeather.setWeatherId(weatherData.getWeatherId());
          curWeather.setDescription(weatherData.getDescription());
          curWeather.setHumidity(weatherData.getHumidity());
          curWeather.setPressure(weatherData.getPressure());
          curWeather.setTemperature(weatherData.getTemperature());
          curWeather.setWindDirection(weatherData.getWindDirection());
          curWeather.setWindSpeed(weatherData.getWindSpeed());
      }
```

Where the code before the else checks the table for an existing record for the day and weatherData is a object that contains data collected. Is there a better, less verbose way of updating the daily record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use uniqueResult instead of list**

Check out the method uniqueResult() here:  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29

Then you can do the following:

```
Weather curWeather = (Weather) session.createQuery(query.toString()).uniqueResult();
```

*Side Note*
Trusting weatherData.getDate() is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Instead use named query parameters.  These are tokens of the form :name in the query string. A value is bound to the parameter :weatherDate by calling

```
session.createQuery("from Weather where COLUMN_DATE = :weatherDate")
  .setParameter("weatherDate", weatherData.getDate());
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  Will invest in reading about uniqueResult but what are the benefits versus the current approach?

Comment: It removes the 10 lines of code following the query.  Because you are querying for a specific object hibernate will populate the Weather object for you.  Happy reading!

Comment: Minor nit - the createQuery call has to cast the result to weather using java 1.7 - Weather curWeather = (Weather)session.createQuery(query.toString()).uniqueResult();

Comment: That is correct, I didn't check to see if the code compiles, I'll edit the code above.  If you found the solution to be helpful, go ahead and accept it as the answer.